# Package-level exports, circular dependencies

Tags: python, import

I have the following package:

```
foo/
    __init__.py:
        from .body import UsefulClass
        from .another import AnotherClass

    body.py:

        from . import utll
        class UsefulClass:
            util.do_something()

    another.py:

        class AnotherClass: ...

    util.py:

        def do_something...
```

The idea is, when someone imports `foo`, they should be able to use `foo.UsefulClass` without worrying about the internal structure of the package. In other words, I don't want them to import `foo.body`, just `foo`.

However, when I do `from . import util` in `body.py` this also imports `__init__.py`, which in turn imports `body` once again. I realize that python handles this situation well, however I'm not comfortable having this obviously circular dependency.

Is there a better way to export things at the package level without creating circular dependencies in imports?

PS: I'd like to avoid in-function imports

Comment: python would throw an ImportError and tell you of a circular dependency. so this is fine. Also in some situations in-function imports can help avoid circular dependency issues.

Comment: Is the above setup matching your *actual* problem? If yes, and you run into the circular import error, it's a little weird, because the above shouldn't result in errors (as the answer below suggests). What's your python version, maybe something was different in the past?

Answer (score 3):

I think your initial premise is wrong. If you do an `import foo` statement with your current setup, ***__init__.py*** and ***body.py*** will only be imported once as can be shown by putting a print statement as the first line in each of those files:

The layout of directory ***foo*** (I have omitted ***another.py***, since its presence or absence is not relevant):

[image]

**File *__init__.py*:**

```py
print('__init__.py imported')

from .body import UsefulClass
```

**File *body.py*:**

```py
print('body.py imported')

from . import util

class UsefulClass:
    x = util.do_something()
```

**File *util.py*:**

```py
def do_something():
    return 9
```

**And finally:**

```py
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import foo
__init__.py imported
body.py imported
>>> foo.UsefulClass.x
9
>>>
```